# How to stop pydoc from erroring out on f-strings?

Tags: python, syntax-error, docstring, pydoc, f-string

I am using `pydoc` to automatically build documentation.  My code is written for Python 3.6.

It errors out with the following error: `<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax`.  It happens whenever I use an `f-string`.

**Can you help me figure out why?**

When I run `which pydoc` I get: `/usr/local/bin/pydoc`

**Sample Code**

Here is some sample code, called `test.py`:

```
"""This is a docstring."""


def my_method():
    """Another docstring."""
    print(
        f"This is a really really really really really really really really "
        f"really really really really really long string."
    )
    pass
```

**Results**

And when I run `pydoc test` on this is the output: `problem in ./test.py - <type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'>: invalid syntax (test.py, line 7)`.  Note: this line is an `f-string`.

When (from within `ipython`) I say: `help('test')`, this is the output:

```
Help on module test:

NAME
    test - This is a docstring.

FUNCTIONS
    my_method()
        Another docstring.

FILE
    /Users/james.braza/code/wpi-aladdin-syringe-pump/test.py
```

So the auto-documentation works for Python's `help()` but not for `pydoc`.

Comment: Make sure your pydoc runs on Python 3.6+ as well.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille it errors out while generating the `pydoc`, I have no `f-strings` in my docstrings.  I just reworded question to make this more clear

Comment: The `pydoc` executable is a script that which may be calling a different version of Python. (Running `which pydoc` and inspecting the script may help you confirm this.) To ensure you are running pydoc with Python3.6+, try `/path/to/python3.6 -m pydoc test`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pydoc executable is a script that which may be calling a different version of Python. (Running `which pydoc` and inspecting the script may help you confirm this.) To ensure you are running pydoc with Python3.6+, try

```
/path/to/python3.6 -m pydoc test
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so turns out my problem was quite trivial.  @unutbu in the comments pointed it out, and then later answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57466612/11163122).  I needed to run the `pydoc` script via Python 3.6 or higher.

For me: `python3 -V` returns `Python 3.7.3`.

So running: `python3 -m pydoc test` worked great!!

```
Help on module test:

NAME
    test - This is a docstring.

FUNCTIONS
    my_method()
        Another docstring.

FILE
    /Users/james.braza/code/wpi-aladdin-syringe-pump/test.py
```